# Done is not working in softKeyboard in Autocomplete TextView in android

Tags: android

I have One AutocompleTextView and I want to  make the virtual keyboard disappear when he hits "DONE" at the AutocompleTextView. So far, the buttons "NEXT"/"DONE" do nothing at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code/xml declaring the AutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: <AutoCompleteTextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:maxLength="2"  
            android:numeric="integer|signed|decimal" 
            android:textStyle="normal" 
            android:typeface="normal" 
            android:hint="Tip %" 
            android:id="@+id/editViewTip" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="30sp"
             android:textSize="16sp" android:layout_width="150sp"/>

Answer (score 18):

Add this Property to your `AutoCompleteTextView` in `xml`:

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Comment: android:inputType="text" was also required in order for it to work properly for me

Answer (score 12):

The following works for all the Views which support imeOptions; for instance `EditText`, `TextView`, `AutocompleteTextView`, etc.

In your xml:

```
<autocompleteTextView

inputType = "text"
imeOptions = "actionDone"
/>
```

In Java:

```
autocomplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) issueDetailView.findViewById(R.id.yourId);
autocomplete.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
               if(actionId== EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                  //do Whatever you Want to do
               }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: problem with this is that i cannot get it to have more then one line of text, both `android:minLines` and `android:lines` dont work with this solution for me.

Comment: I'd like to point out that inputType = "text" is necessary for imeOption to work. I didn't have it and was seing the return button

Answer (score 8):

Just add the following on yours XML layout file:

```
  android:imeOptions="actionDone"
  android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: I think this may be a bug in Android, something to do with backward compatibility or even maybe device specific. IME options won't work without single line (depreciated), even when max-lines is specified.

Comment: What if we want multiline enable?

Comment: by default autocompletetextview singleline property remains false that's why when just put  android:imeOptions="actionDone" the soft keyboard doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Check [android:imeOptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions) attribute.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `android:imeOptions` only works if i set `android:inputType` which is

`android:inputType="textAutoComplete" android:imeOptions="actionDone"`