# AutoCompleteTextView with keyboard done button and maxLines

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, autocompletetextview

I am trying to implement AutoCompleteTextView with multiline text and with keyboard done button. But done button does not show on keyboard (shows enter button). Same thing i have tried with `android:singleLine="true"` and text comes in single line with done button.

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtVillageName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/edt_border"
                        android:cursorVisible="true"
                        android:maxLines="4"
                        android:hint="Enter your location"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/lblColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />
```

Comment: add inputtype in xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Done is not working in softKeyboard in Autocomplete TextView in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109516/done-is-not-working-in-softkeyboard-in-autocomplete-textview-in-android)

Comment: One question 4 u!, you want 4 line with done imeOption, how you will hit enter for next line?

Comment: use `android:inputType="text"`

Comment: android:inputType="text" works shows done but for single line. I want text should wrap and show in multi line.

Comment: Is this possible in case of AutocompleteTextView ?

Comment: mAutocompleteTextView.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
mAutocompleteTextView.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);     with android:inputType="text" works.   Thanks guys !!!

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:imeActionLabel="Done"` into your `xml` code

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/txtVillageName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:hint="Enter your location"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:imeActionLabel="Done"
        android:singleLine="true" />
```

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

android:inputType="text" works.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtVillageName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:cursorVisible="true"
                        android:hint="@string/location_hint"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/lblColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />
```

Set HorizontalScrolling and MaxLines

```
mAutocompleteTextView.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
mAutocompleteTextView.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

It works