# How to get "Done" to show and exit keyboard on AutoCompleteTextiView in Android?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, imeoptions

**My problem:** I'm using an **`AutoCompleteTextView`** list of options for the user and despite having the activity xml setup with **`android:imeOptions="actionDone"`** the keyboard still provides a return option instead presenting the keyboard with the "Done" option.

**What I have tried:** I searched a few posts but could not find one with this specific issue. So I tried the following solution posted from another post applicable for **`EditText`**, so I could apply this "Done" action to multiple AutoCompleteTextViews within the same activity (posted [here](http://tonylukasavage.com/blog/2011/06/02/android-quick-tip--edittext-with-done-button-that-closes-the-keyboard/)).

Again, the issue is that despite the XML **`AutoCompleteTextView`** is setup for **`actionDone`** the keyboard shows the return arrow.

**XML**

```java
 <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/viewSource"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_source"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/lblViewSource"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/lblViewSource"/>
```

**The AutoCompleteTextView calling code**

```java
sourceTitle.setOnEditorActionListener(new DoneOnEditorActionListener());
```

**Custom Class Code for managing "Done" and keyboard close**

```java
class DoneOnEditorActionListener implements AutoCompleteTextView.OnEditorActionListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following ended up solving my problem. Once I added and defined the **`inputType`** in the activity XML the done button appeared. So, it appears that the **`inputType`** needs defined with the **`imeOptions`** or the done button will not appear. This was one of the suggestions from the following link though none of answers were approved.

[Done is not working in softKeyboard in Autocomplete TextView in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109516/done-is-not-working-in-softkeyboard-in-autocomplete-textview-in-android)

```
android:inputType="text"
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```